# Does anybody know why this error occurs in the folloving code?ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: n= int(input("Enter any number: "))

Tags: python, valueerror

I wrote the following code but every time I submit it to Hackerank.com a mistake is popping out. What should I do to solve this issue?
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n= int(input("Enter any number: "))'

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
            n = int(input("Enter any number: ").strip())
            if n % 2 != 0:
                print("Weird")
            else:
                if n >= 2 and n <= 5:
                    print("Not Weird")
                elif n >= 6 and n <= 20:`enter code here`
                    print("Weird")
                elif n > 2`enter code here`0:
                    print("Not Weird")
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but do you know that instead of `n >= 2 and n <= 5` you can write `2 <= n <= 5` and instead of `n >= 6 and n <= 20` you can write `6 <= n <= 20`?

Comment: Supress the extra strings `enter code here` you have two of them and they produce errors. Check all indentation of 4 spaces. Otherwise it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

In the above code you are converting the input to integer. Hackerrank will have a n number of test cases. One test case among those cases might have a character has input. When you try to convert a string character to int python will throw an error saying invalid int literal. Below code can be helpful.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
            n = input("Enter any number: ").strip()
            if n.isdigit():
                if n % 2 != 0:
                    print("Weird")
                else:
                    if n >= 2 and n <= 5:
                        print("Not Weird")
                    elif n >= 6 and n <= 20:
                        print("Weird")
                    elif n > 20:
                        print("Not Weird")
            else:
                print("Not all characters are integers")
```